# Import gmail account with MVC3 Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

Can anyone help me on the thread below?

I have written code to import Gmail contacts and it's working fine in my local server 
but when I publish it on Azure server it is throwing the exception below:

> Google.GData.Client.InvalidCredentialsException: Invalid credentials
>   at
>   Google.GData.Client.Utilities.QueryClientLoginToken(GDataCredentials
>   gc, String serviceName, String applicationName, Boolean fUseKeepAlive,
>   IWebProxy proxyServer, Uri clientLoginHandler) at
>   Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.QueryAuthToken(GDataCredentials
>   gc) at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.EnsureCredentials() at
>   Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.EnsureWebRequest() at
>   Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.EnsureWebRequest() at
>   Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute() at
>   Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter) at
>   Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(Uri queryUri, DateTime
>   ifModifiedSince, String etag, Int64& contentLength) at
>   Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(FeedQuery feedQuery) at
>   Google.GData.Client.Feed`1.get_AtomFeed() at
>   Google.GData.Client.Feed`1.d__0.MoveNext() at
>   RCFO.SocialPlugins.Google.GoogleExtract.FetchGoogleContacts(String
>   appName, String userName, String password, String& GoogleError) in

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about azure.. but I'd go by the following line "Google.GData.Client.InvalidCredentialsException"... have you double checked that you're logging in with the correct credentials?

Comment: Yup,I did check Credentials are correct.

Comment: could you supply some code. It's hard giving and decent advice with just a stack trace to go by. :P

Answer (score 0):

Any source? I don't know much about the Google gmail contacts API. If it is the same code that works local, and fails in Azure, I would first look to any IIS/security context changes, and then network port/firewall changes.